# SQL - how to output a list of objects with only one certain attribute?

Tags: sql

For example we have:

```
name fruit
-------------
bill apple
bill orange
lily apple
emma orange
```

I only want to output a list of people who have apple as their ONLY attribute. so the list would only include Lily.

How would I do that?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You just need `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT name FROM
table t
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT (*) = 1 and
       SUM(CASE WHEN fruit = 'apple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Comment: I think you could also have "and min(fruit) = 'apple' " as the second condition of the having clause. That would simplify the query a bit

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
select distinct name
from your_table_name a
where fruit = 'apple' and name not in (select name from your_table_name b where b.name = a.name and b.fruit!='apple')
```